# Force Multi-Line strings into a single line in NLog

Tags: c#, nlog

I'm using NLog in my application and want to read the resulting log-file with another.
Problem: In some rare instances the log contains strings with multiple line. Most notable, and the least influencable are stacktraces of exceptions.
For ease of implementation, the second app should only have to deal with single lines.

Is there an option to force NLog to only write single lines?
I'm fine with either keeping the linebreaks (e.g. as \n) or with them removed..

If there is an easy way to read an NLog file that I'm not aware of, I'd appreciate a comment about that, too.

Comment: You can consider `${replace-newlines:${message}}` or `${replace-newlines:${exception}}`. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Replace-NewLines-Layout-Renderer

Comment: NLog JsonLayout can also be used which escape newlines in output: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/JsonLayout